# Energy of a free spin $\frac{1}{2}$ particle in the absence of a magnetic field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

I'm wondering if the mere presence of spin will contribute to the energy of a particle, also in the absence of a magnetic field? For I know that a magnetic field will break the degeneracy between the up and down state via
$$ \hat{H}_\text{precession} = - \frac{g e}{m_e c} \mathbf{S} \cdot \mathbf{B} $$
but suppose I have a free particle with spin $\frac{1}{2}$. Does the Hamiltonian become something like
$$ \hat{H} = - \frac{\hbar}{2 m}\nabla^2 \pm A \mathbf{S}^2$$
where $A$ is a constant to fix the units?

I apologize if this is a noobish question but I can't find this explicitly in my text books, most pages seem to concern precession.

- If no such extra term is needed, why not? If the particle had orbital angular momentum $\mathbf{L}$ then there would be a term proportional to $\mathbf{L}^2$ right? Because surely there has to be non-zero energy associated with non-zero angular momentum. So then there must be a contribution from $\mathbf{S}^2$ as well?

Answer (score 1):

First, let me note that in the suggested Hamiltonian the spin states have the same energy, which in both cases is shifted by
$$\pm A\mathbf{S}^2 = \pm A\frac{\hbar^2}{4}.$$

On a more general level - whether the Hamiltonian depends on the square or the higher powers of spin and orbital angular momenta depends on the situation: what are the external potentials, what interactions are taken into account, etc.

The Hamiltonian for a *non-relativistic free particle* includes spin only via the Zeeman term - here *free* means no potentials and interactions with other particles. A relativistic spin-1/2 particle is described by the Dirac equation, where spin components are not independent on momenta. One often includes the first relativistic correction - the spin-orbit coupling in - the non-relativistic Schrödinger equation, since it is often too important to be neglected: in this case the state of the particle depends on its spin even in absence of magnetic field. Finally, in many-body systems one often has to deal with spin-spin interactions dependent on the position in space or carried dynamically by some of the particles - in this case spin and orbital degrees of motion are also coupled.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer, although it doesn't quite address my fundamental question: does the mere presence of spin contribute to the energy of a free particle and if not, why not? As you say, ordinarily spin only comes into play as the Zeeman effect but surely an angular momentum of sorts should always contribute to the energy? If we construct a QM rigid rotor we also get a contribution $\propto J^2$ in the Hamiltonian after all.

Your remark about the spin-orbit coupling is a very good one, I'll look into that again as QM classes have been a while.

Comment: There is no single answer for all systems. The energy will depend on spin, if the Hamiltonian contains terms that couple spin to other degrees of freedom, which are usually orbital. In relativistic case it is always like this, because existence of spin follows from fundamental symetries. In non-relativistic case the spin is introduced *ad-hoc*, simply because we know that it exists, and all interactions with spin are likewise introduced phenomenologically.